# Choosing Recipient Email on Laravel Email Verification

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I had implemented [email verification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification)  in my Laravel application. By default, when a user is registered, the verification email is sent to the user. However, what I want is to send a verification email to my email, that is, to choose the recipient, so the site administrator (in this case, me) can approve the user registration.

Is there any way to do this? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I would not recommend the default user email verification that comes with Laravel which is `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;`

If you are wanting to make it so users have to be approved by administrators I would set up a secondary field which is not `email_verified_at`.

Modify your user migration `database/migrations/*********_create_users_table.php` and add a boolean field.

```php
...
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    ...
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            ...
            $table->boolean('approved');
            ...
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can create a new middleware which checks if the user is approved.

For triggering the email I would add the event which is fired when a user is registered in the listen array `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`

```php
...
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
            /* add some notification here that sends you an email */
        ],
    ];
...
```

Sorry this answer is not to detailed but it will get you going.